# Jenkins GitHub org last build status icon

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-github-plugin

I have Jenkins configured such that it scanned my entire organization and created jobs for every repo that had a PR with a Jenkinsfile.  This worked fine and I'm getting the builds running.

My problem is these repo icons on the left column:

[image]

These are supposed to be "status of last build" icons.  Is there any way to change this?  This is really not useful as I need to click into each job to see what the last status was.

Comment: I have created a ticket for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117063/jenkins-github-org-last-build-status-icon